# ModuleNotFoundError with package installed from github

Tags: python, testing, directory, anaconda, python-3.7

I installed a package in my anaconda environment by entering the following line: 
`pip3 install -e git+https://github.com/gauravmm/jupyter-testing.git#egg=jupyter-testing`

I keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testing'` on line: `from testing.testing import test`. I have no idea why this is happening, and believe it has something to do with the way my directory structure is set up.

My directory tree looks like this:

```
├── hw1_get_started.ipynb
├── requirements.txt
└── src
    └── jupyter-testing
        ├── jupyter_testing.egg-info
        │   ├── dependency_links.txt
        │   ├── PKG-INFO
        │   ├── SOURCES.txt
        │   └── top_level.txt
        ├── LICENSE
        ├── README.md
        ├── setup.py
        └── testing
            ├── __init__.py
            └── testing.py
```

I am trying to use this module : https://github.com/gauravmm/jupyter-testing.git#egg=jupyter-testing to do some testing in an online class.

I appreciate any help and explanation as to what I am doing wrong! :)

Comment: Make sure you active your environment first, then use `pip` instead of `pip3`. It's also always a good idea to check which `pip` you are about to use, e.g., `which pip`.

Comment: @merv why pip instead of pip3? Also, it worked, so thank you very much as well.

Comment: Conda installs `pip` as `pip`, no matter the Python version in the env. It doesn't provide an alias (e.g., `pip2` or `pip3`), so when you ran `pip3` you were likely invoking a `pip` associated with a different Python installation.

Comment: Ahh I see that makes sense. Thank you.